# Create a package for debian that contain other program/deb package

Tags: debian, executable

I need to create a package or an executable program that will install some other deb package like tightvnc... So basically when I user execute my package, tightvnc will be installed, and configured, and the user will be prompted to enter a password for tightvnc server.

How can I go about this? Is there any tool out there that can create this kind of executable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "user execute my package". can you give more details about what you are trying to do? Note that installing a package on a normal Debian system as a regular user is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/equivs

Circumvent Debian package dependencies

This package provides a tool to create trivial Debian packages. Typically these packages contain only dependency information, but they can also include normal installed files like other packages do.

One use for this is to create a metapackage: a package whose sole purpose is to declare dependencies and conflicts on other packages so that these will be automatically installed, upgraded, or removed.